# Calculo de horas

Tags: algoritmo, lógica

Preciso calcular a hora exata que determinado registro tem para ser analisado.

Cada **registro** possui um **intervalo** em que pode ser analisado e,  um valor máximo em horas, referente ao **prazo** para analise.

#### Exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Hora final = Data cadastro + Prazo = **26/12/2014 04:24:31**

Mas preciso que as horas fora do intervalo sejam ignoradas, ou seja:

- Do dia 25 seria contabilizado apenas 01:35:29, pois o intervalo é até as 22h
- Voltaria a contagem a partir das 08h, finalizando a hora exata as **26/12/2014 14:24:31**

Minha solução atual é um `loop` para cada registro:

```
$incremento = 0
$cadastro = "26/12/2014 04:24:31"
$intervalo_inicial = 8
$intervalo_final = 10
$prazo = 8

while ($incremento <> $prazo) {
    if ($cadastro >= $intervalo_inicial) and ($cadastro <= $intervalo_final) {
        $incremento += 1
    }
    // adiciona 1 hora
    $cadastro = date($cadastro, strtotime('1 hour'));
}
```

Porém, calcular 100.000 registro torna a tarefa bem lenta. Qualquer tipo de solução é valida, banco de dados, fórmula, lógica..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar divisão para saber quantos dias inteiros você usou e quantas horas sobraram.

Pra evitar confusão nesse exemplo (devido a dois valores diferentes valendo 8), troquei o prazo para 7 horas. Além disso, na versão de verdade eu usaria a unidade mínima de contagem de tempo para fazer as contas (segundos ou milisegundos, depende do que você estiver usando) mas no exemplo eu representei tudo usando horas para ficar mais claro.

```
$tempo_inicio = 20:24:31 - 08:00:00  // = 12:24:31
$prazo = 07:00:00
$tempo_fim = $hora_inicio + $prazo // = 19:24:31

$horas_por_dia = 22:00:00 - 08:00:00 // = 14:00:00

// quociente e resto da divisão
$dias_gastos = $tempo_fim / $horas_por_dia  // 1
$horas_ultimo_dia = $tempo_fim % $horas_por_dia // 5:24:31

$dia_fim = $dia_inicio + $dias_gastos // dia 26
$hora_fim = 8:00:00 + $horas_ultimo_dia // 13:24:31
```

Comment: Perfeito @hugomg, só alterei o `$dias_gastos = $prazo/24`, em algumas situações tava contando +1 dia

Comment: Que casos que tava dando o valor errado? Dividindo por 24 você não ignora as horas fora do intervalo...